# Sql I have a string I want to store as a datetime

Tags: sql, string, datetime

I have strings, these are stored as a varchar(50) but I want to store them as a datetime in a different table/column. Anyone have an idea on how to convert them easily?

```
2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:02:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:03:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:04:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:05:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:06:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:07:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:08:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:09:00-06:00
2015-05-31 19:10:00-06:00
```

I have tried  the following .... timeStr is a varchar(50) and date_time is a datetime.  This is in MSSql

insert into temp (timeStr, date_time)
  values ('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00','2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00' );

insert into temp (timeStr, date_time)
  values ('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00',convert(datetime,'2015-05-31 19:01:00-    06:00') );

insert into temp (timeStr, date_time)
  values ('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00',cast('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00' as datetime) );

Comment: What does the `-06:00` means here?

Comment: Can you tell something about your efforts? What's your DBMS. In MySQL there is a simple [way](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: it should work, if you change the column type to datetime. there's no need to convert

Comment: I have tried  the following .... timeStr is a varchar(50) and date_time is a datetime.  This is in MSSql 


insert into temp (timeStr, date_time)
values ('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00','2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00' );

insert into temp (timeStr, date_time)
values ('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00',convert(datetime,'2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00') );

insert into temp (timeStr, date_time)
values ('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00',cast('2015-05-31 19:01:00-06:00' as datetime) );

Answer (score 0):

This is very well documented, see here: [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using PHP to parse the string to epoch time and storing that as an int.

Answer (score 0):

In **MySQL** there is a simple solution using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, which works passing as parameter a formatted string and a string with the [format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). For your example, in order to get rid of the trailing chars after the date, I've used the [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function too.

Assuming that the name of your table is *foo*, the name of the varchar(50) field is *CH*, and *DT* the name of the datetime (I'm in a lack of fantasy for the names today...), the query is:

```
UPDATE foo SET DT=STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(CH,19),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```